# Correlate two groups of variables as two variables in SPSS

Tags: variables, correlation, spss

I have two groups of variables (stress & anger). Stress group contains 5 variables and anger group contains 6 variables. Is there a way to correlate (spearman) stress and anger like two variables? Not the 5 stress and 6 anger variables, but stress and anger like two variables that contain the other variables somehow.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com.  It sounds like what you're trying to do is create "summary" variables for stress and anger and then see how those are correlated.  It may be possible to get to that goal by performing some principal components analysis on the data, but the choice of statistical technique isn't really a programming question, which is what this site is for.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, the answer is no unless you create a summary or combination of each set into a single entity.